# Foreign language words similar to Hebrew words

Tags: hebrew, language, greek

I started compiling a list about a year ago of all of the times I noticed that an English word was very linguistically similar to a Hebrew word phonetically and semantically (i.e. in meaning). Many have seen or heard the [Rashi on Genesis 11:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.11.1?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) :"The whole earth had one language" - The Holy Tongue. That is, all languages descend from Hebrew. I find it interesting to see how that plays out, aside from it often being very useful in understanding the connotations of a word. We see very often that Rishonim and the Gemara do this (e.g. comparing Hebrew words to words of their language) in order to understand both the connotations *and* denotations of a word. I'd like to make this a Community Wiki where people can contribute the words they observed or realized were very similar to a Hebrew word both phonetically and semantically(I can't find the button though). Here is my list so far:

- פרת-Eu**PHR**a**T**e**S**
- **לינ**ה-Lay/**lean**ing/sleep
- (חרק(ים- crack(s)
- **קרן** זוית-**c**o**rn**er
- **מלש**ינים-**M**a**L**i**CE**? (A bit tenuous)
- איוב-**jov**ial (What an irony! Am I wrong though? Oxford Dictionary: “[Jovial](https://www.lexico.com/definition/jovial) Cheerful and friendly.”)
- ה**שכל**-**schol**arship
- **רג**י**ל**-**reg**u**l**ar
- כף-cup (to cup your hands)
- שיר-cheer
- **פי**ו**ס**-ap**pease**ment/**peace**
- הֲ**שקף** – **F**o**c**u**s** (Hebrew letters backwards/same sounds in both)
- נגד - **N**e**G**a**T**ive (see Rashi Leviticus 19:16 that D and T can switch while retaining the original meaning)
- **חס** ושלום - **H**u**sh** or **חש**אי-Hush(lit. secret or hidden) - Oxford Dictionary: "[hush-hush](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hush-hush) (especially of an official plan or project) highly secret or confidential."
- פיוט-Poet
- **ק**ו**לפ**י`{1}`-**cl**a**p**/Yiddish - "קלאפ"
- נחל-**C**a**N**a**L**
- תיר-**Tour**ist
- לב - **L**o**v**e
- מרת - Mrs.

`{1}`: .ערכין כב:Rashi-“הכאות”

Comment: Hi @Sam - there are few mistakes here... e.g. לב is heart, מלשינים is not malice it comes from the word לשון i.e. language / tongue

Comment: Ironically איוב was someone who was famous for immense suffering and definitely didn't have a 'jovial' experience. The word for jovial would probably be something closer to some form of שמחה, חדוה or עליזה

Comment: @Dov while לב is heart, the heart is nevertheless often connected with love.

Comment: @Harel13 - Agreed but it is not the literal meaning,

Comment: @Dov well he did say similar.

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic

Comment: @Dov I am 100% aware that they are not direct translations. My point evidently didn't get across to you. I was demonstrating how the words have evolved and mutated from their original Hebrew into different meanings while still retaining both their phonetic and semantic origins. Rishonim (often Rashi, Radak, Ibn Ezra) and the gemara very frequently compare words in Hebrew to words in other languages to get a clearer understanding of its connotations, and sometimes even its denotations. I could put examples in the post.

Comment: @robev, I think the last point demonstrates how it is on topic. Maybe I should clarify the question.

Comment: מרת is only relevant to Mrs. if you speak ashkenazis, which I think the consensus says that it's incorrect. Other ones on this list too are a big stretch and don't seem to be more than coincidence.

Comment: @robev what do you mean? I have a family shtar yichus dating back to 1897 which uses the phrase מרת

Comment: According to Menachem Kellner, the Rambam felt that the Hebrew language was not holy per se, nor the original language. Besides, every culture claims to be the origin of everyone else. Indians claim all languages originally derived from Sanskrit, for example. No, the Tower of Babel story is only a parable.

Comment: Given that English has roughly [170,000 words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language#Vocabulary), it is quite probable that with some creativity you'll find similar words in Hebrew. Or words that both Hebrew and English took from another language (e.g. Euphrates, poet).

Comment: http://www.balashon.com/2008/02/koh-i-noor.html is interesting and references Distant Cousins which makes connections

Comment: @sam מרת is a Hebrew word but what does Marat have to do with Mrs.?

Comment: euphrates is probably just an english pronunciation of פרת, so no surprise there.

Comment: @robev See the Rashi on Leviticus 19:16 where he says "all letters which come from the same place of the mouth can be interchanged". Practically this means: g'ronios:(אהחע(ר, sifsiyim:בומפ, cheekeeyos:גיכק, lishoneeyos("tongues"):דטלנת, and sheeneyos("teeth"):זשסרצ. Try setting up your mouth to make the "T" sound. Make the sound. Now make the "S" sound. Do the same for "D", "(Israeli) L", and "N". Notice how your positions barely change.Hence,they can be interchanged and the meaning will stay the same fundamentally.See Hirsh Etymological Dictionary חול=חור=אפל(idea=dark/void/lacking holiness).

Comment: @robev Are you familiar with the phrase "לימודי חול" - "studies of plainness/emptiness"(secular studies/lacking holiness of Torah), or "ימי חול"(days of the week/lacking holiness of Shabbos)?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/296/170

Comment: Don’t forget אונס = onus. Interestingly they oppose each other. אנוס renders one generally free of any legal responsibility where onus (at least according to one definition) renders one worthy of blame or responsibility.